# Using multimethod to force a function input type to be a class within itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple library to handle matrices and vectors. To do this I have created a class vec and inherited a vec2, vec3, and vec4 class from it. In these classes I would like to force the type of certain functions parameters to only accept their own type eg.

```
class vec3 ( vec ):

    @mutlimethod 
    def cross ( self, other : vec3 ):
        #[function code]
```

( using multimethod from here http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605 )

This returns the error "NameError: name 'vec3' is not defined."

So naturally as a C programmer I want to create a class prototype or a forward declaration then define what is in my class again as normal like this:

```
 class vec3;
 class vec3 {
      vec3 cross ( vec3 other ){
          //[function code ]
      }
```

Is there any way to do that in python or is there a better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-reference or forward-reference of type annotations in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193540/self-reference-or-forward-reference-of-type-annotations-in-python)