# Self-reference or forward-reference of type annotations in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, typechecking, typing

I'm trying to figure out how self-reference of types work with [python3's type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) - the docs don't specify anything regarding this.

As an example:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Optional, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')
class Node(Generic[T]):
    left = None
    right = None
    value = None

    def __init__(
        self, value: Optional[T],
        left: Optional[Node[T]]=None,
        right: Optional[Node[T]]=None,
    ) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

This code generates the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "node.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Node(Generic[T]):
  File "node.py", line 12, in Node
    right: Optional[Node[T]]=None,
NameError: name 'Node' is not defined
```

This is using Python 3.5.1

Comment: Hmmm, `typing` is available only from 3.5. Check [whatsnew of 3.5 version](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html)

Comment: @thefourtheye: I edited the question. I just installed 3.5.1 and the problem still exists. The reason I had it working with 3.4 was because I had mypy installed

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[PEP 0484 - Type Hints - The problem of forward declarations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-problem-of-forward-declarations) addresses the issue:

> The problem with type hints is that annotations (per [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) , and
>   similar to default values) are evaluated at the time a function is
>   defined, and thus any names used in an annotation must be already
>   defined when the function is being defined. A common scenario is a
>   class definition whose methods need to reference the class itself in
>   their annotations. (More general, it can also occur with mutually
>   recursive classes.) This is natural for container types, for example:
>
> ...
>
> As written this will not work, because of the peculiarity in Python
>   that class names become defined once the entire body of the class has
>   been executed. **Our solution, which isn't particularly elegant, but
>   gets the job done, is to allow using string literals in annotations.**
>   Most of the time you won't have to use this though -- most uses of
>   type hints are expected to reference builtin types or types defined in
>   other modules.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Optional, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')
class Node(Generic[T]):
    left = None
    right = None
    value = None

    def __init__(
        self,
        value: Optional[T],
        left: Optional['Node[T]']=None,
        right: Optional['Node[T]']=None,
    ) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

---

```
>>> import typing
>>> typing.get_type_hints(Node.__init__)
{'return': None,
 'value': typing.Union[~T, NoneType],
 'left': typing.Union[__main__.Node[~T], NoneType],
 'right': typing.Union[__main__.Node[~T], NoneType]}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I completely missed that part - it even has a similar example to mine!

Comment: and what about a dictionnary self referencing itself? For example MyDict=TypedDict('MyDict',{'callback': Callable[[MyDict], None]} What I want to do is add a key/value in a dict, the value is a callback funcion taking as first argument the MyDict itself ...

Comment: i don't know, however disappointing this situation is, i think such a workaround is a bit too much just to get autocompletion working. Can't we just use good old docstrings for that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62227759/1312695

Comment: @user1312695, You can. But you will lose mypy-like tools checks.

Comment: @falsetru, that's right. However, if you use "type: " hints, it turns out that mypy does work (have just checked that): http://i.imgur.com/Sdwx02V.png

Comment: @user1312695, It's not a doc-string but a comment.

Comment: @user1312695, If you're using Python 3.7+, `from __future__ import annotations` will allow you to use ``Optional[Node[T]]`. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/

Comment: @falsetru, you are right, types in a comment is a different approach to what i initially meant.

Comment: Turning off `mypy` warnings/errors is not a good solution to resolving type issues.